# TweetSharp: How do i display username net to the users name in my listView?

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

Hello im currently trying to fix so that my listview displays 2 columns, one which displays the tweet and the second one displaying the tweets owner(the user). how do i do this? i've come this far:

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        listbox1.Items.Clear();
        tweetid.Items.Clear();

        TwitterSearchResult inc = service.Search(new SearchOptions { Q = "stuff", Lang = "en" });
        IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> status = inc.Statuses;


        foreach (var tweet in inc.Statuses)
        {


            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(tweet.Text);

            item.SubItems.Add(tweet.Text);
            item.SubItems.Add(tweet.Text);


            listView2.Items.Add(item);
```

I sorta want to include a new Tweetsharp command in the same variable "tweet". Is this possible. im thinking i have to add a new IEnumerable<>.
Any help would be thankfully accepted.

OH AND ONE MORE THING! :)

How come that tweetsharp only returns a 100 tweets max? Is there a way to solve this too? :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> one which displays the tweet and the second one displaying the tweets owner(the user)

Well, taking a quick look at [the objects you're using](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp/tree/master/src/TweetSharp), it appears that `TwitterStatus` has a `User` property of type `TwitterUser`, which itself has a `Name` property.  Does the intellisense disagree with this?

> im thinking i have to add a new IEnumerable<>

Why?  You currently have a collection of `TwitterStatus` objects, which seem to contain all the information you need.  Are you just looking to do this?:

```
item.SubItems.Add(tweet.Text);
item.SubItems.Add(tweet.User.Name);
```

From that collection (`IEnumerable<>`) of `TwitterStatus` objects you are able to extract all the information about those tweets.  Just display the information you want to display.

Comment: Gosh im so stupid... Thank you. i havent really grasped c# on a good level yet. This was exactly what i was looking for: 

item.SubItems.Add(tweet.Text);
item.SubItems.Add(tweet.User.Name);

Sometimes long period programming can make you slow in the head :-). I got the listView to show me the results i want, now i've started adding more columns. But when i try to add tweet.Id it says: 

Error 3 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'long' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewGroup' 

is the a way to convert to long?
Thanks once again!